# qgraphicsview preferred size

Tags: qt, size, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am now trying to resize a qgraphicsview to a preffered size:
I am using layouts:

```
this->layout()->addWidget(&qtview);
```

I have layouts everywhere, so thet the size of my main widow is adjusted depending on its contents.

If I use:

```
qtview.setMinimumWidth(500);
qtviewSetMinimumHeight(500);
```

Then my view is scaled to the given size, but I am not able to shrink the main window. (which makes sense as I set a minimum soze)

I would like to tell qt my preferred (not minimum or maximum) size for the view, letting the view use scrollbars when needed (i.e. if the preferred size does not fit in my screen), or letting qt have a smaller view than my preferred size if the scene is smaller than my view, (or enlarge the scene to fit the view in this case)

I am searching for something looking like an hypothetical method `setPreferredWidth()`.

What can I do to get this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for the QGraphicsView function setSizePolicy: -

```
setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but no it is not. I have read about that, but I don't know how to set the preferred size. The answer may be a combinaison of these Policy and something else to set the size. That is this something else I am looking for. 
If I set the size with `setMinimumWidth()` or `setMinumumWeight()` and then apply your suggested policy, then the window will not let be shrink it, i.e. the size is minimum, not preferred.
So how do I tell the width and height that are to be preferred?

Comment: I have tried to overload the sizeHint() as well with no result. Just setting the minimum/Maximum seams to have an effect, but not the effect I want...

Comment: Just set the size policy with preferred size, but don't set the minimum / maximum size. If that's not working, then it's likely that the size policy of another widget in the layout is affecting the overall dimensions.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand: what do you meant by "Just set the size policy with preferred size"? What function do you mean?
`setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Preferred));` tells that some dimension is preferred, but my question remains: How do I tell the dimension (width, heigth) that is preferred?. sorry for not understanding what you meant and thanks for your answers!

Comment: The setMinimumWidth and setMinimumHeight do just that; stop the view getting any smaller, so you don't want to set that. Likewise with the maximum values. If you set the size of the view to what you want and the sizepolicy to preferred, the view will tend towards the preferred size (the size it starts as), but can then grow or shrink appropriately within its layout.

Comment: thanks for your help. We agree I should not use the `setMinimum()` or `setMaximum()`.
Can you please quote the code you'd use to "set the size of the view to what you want"?. Thanks.